# Как сделать, чтобы в свойстве get возвращал int, а set принимал double?

Tags: c#, .net

Сейчас работает следующим образом.

```
...
double Value { get { return a; } set { a = value; } };
double a;
...
Value = 3.14;
int valueCopy = (int)Value;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вариант, чтобы int возвращался 100%

```
private double _doubleValue;

public object DoubleValue
{
    set
    {
        _doubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(value);
    }
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(_doubleValue);;
    }
}
```

---

### **UPD:**

как оказалось, предыдущее решение не верно, поэтому найдёно новое, не знаю на сколько оно приемлимое с точки зрения правильности такого подхода=)

```
class StrangeClass // по-моему такой класс называют прокси классом, могу ошибаться
{
    public double DoubleValue{get;set;}
    public int IntValue{get;set;}

    public StrangeClass(double d)
    {
        DoubleValue = d;
        IntValue = Convert.ToInt32(DoubleValue);
    }

    public static implicit operator StrangeClass(double d)
    {
        return new StrangeClass(d);
    }

    public static implicit operator int(StrangeClass d)
    {
        return d.IntValue;
    }
}

class A
{
    private StrangeClass _value;

    public StrangeClass Value
    {
        set{ _value = value; }
        get{ return _value; }
    }
}

// использование:

A a = new A();
a.Value=3.14;
int b = a.Value;
```

Comment: О, спасибо. То, что нужно.

Comment: Ну да, так можно. Можно сказать, что я ошибся. Только вот на самом деле вернем мы не int (честно не знаю, но там сработает неявное приведение? или все же надо будет опять приводить?)

Comment: `obj.DoubleValue.GetType()` возвравщает System.Int32, я же написал 100%=)

Comment: Да, только прийдется делать опять a = (int)obj.DoubleValue;
Жаль.

Comment: А не появится проблема, то что мы можем что угодно в Value передать?

Comment: и у меня ругается на такой код int a = instance.Value;

Comment: @rasmisha, если попытаться передать что попало, то Convert выкинет исключение. `int a = instance.Value` и правда не проходит, а с `var` проходит и как я сказал, `GetType()` возвращает int, но любая операция с ним вызывает исключение неявного преобразования, странно, однако

Comment: Ну в исключении мало хорошего

С var вообще читать код еще то удовольствие :)

Comment: О! Новый вариант лучше, но громоздкий :).

Comment: и надо будет хорошенько над "говорящими" названиями классов и свойств поработать, а то запутаться легко будет

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя, можно только округлить

```
get { return (int)a; }
```

Но вернется все равно double

И как я понял это делается внутри класса. Зачем тогда идет обращение к свойству?

UPD Могу предложить такой вариант

```
    double Value
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; }
    }

    int ValueInt
    {
        get { return (int)a; }
    }
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Обращение внутри класса не идет. Из вне нужна возможность задавать свойство как double, а возвращать всегда int.